# Accessing a global variable of iframe from parent window

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am trying to access a global variable (Storage object) defined in iframe window from a parent window. Here is what i have tried but i am getting an Uncaught TypError :

> Cannot read property 'Storage' of undefined.

**js for iframe with id:iframe**

```
Storage.prototype.removeObject = function (key)
{
    this.removeItem(key);
    console.log('item removed');
}
```

**js for parent window**

```
const iFrame = $('#iframe');
iFrame.contentWindow.Storage.removeItem("mapsTracking");
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you declare `Storage`, are you sure it is a global *property* at all?

Comment: Btw, your method is on `Storage.prototype` not a static method on `Storage`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today. The "window.parent.variableName" did the trick for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can try directly adding the method on Storage

```
Storage.removeObject = function (key)
{
    this.removeItem(key);
    console.log('item removed');
}
```

Comment: i have this error : 'document.getElementById(...).contentWindow.Storage.removeItem' is not a function

Comment: The name of the method you want to add is "removeObject" and the one you are calling is "removeItem". Please check that once